# Executing post method after JS confirmation

Tags: javascript, html

I am using **ASP .Net MVC 4** , **razor**

on a form , in submit action, i want to set a confirm dialog of javascript. if i click "Ok" post method will be executed. else will not. so i used:

```
<td ><input type="submit" value="Process" name="btnProcess" onclick="confirm('Proceed?')"/></td>
```

but after clicking **cancel** it is executing the controller. How do i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<td ><input type="submit" value="Process" name="btnProcess" onclick="return confirm('Proceed?')"/></td>
```